# What happened to Surpanakha after Ravana's death?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, ramcharitmanas

What happened to Surpanakha after Ravana's death. I heard some stories related to her which I refused to believe in. I couldn't find any post which mentions what happened to her. Is there any reference to this in any version of Ramayana? I read in a post here that her husband was killed by Ravana. I also want to know did she ever got married again?

Comment: Sorry, had to reject [your edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXCWT.png). @AupakaranaAbhibhaa